# Articles show some of text

Tags: posts

This is now my homepage and my articles there is with full text this look bad e.g.:

---

[image]

How i can edit this to look like from this photo so with images and e.g. some of text and after write ''read more'' or just ''...'' which redirect on articles

---

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your home page is using [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content). Use [`the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) instead. The template your home page would be using is either index.php, or front-page.php. Refer to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) image for more information.